# World cup winner as manager and captain

Tags: football, trivia, history, world-cup

Didier Deschamps might achieve the feat of winning FIFA World Cup both as captain (1998) and manager (2018) for France.

I know Franz Beckenbauer had already done it before. Is there any other person to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 footballers who won the World Cup both as a player and as a coach:

> [Mário Zagallo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1rio_Zagallo), Brazil (1958 & 1962 as player, 1970 as coach)
>
> [Franz Beckenbauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Beckenbauer), West Germany (1974 as player, 1990 as coach)
>
> [Didier Deschamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didier_Deschamps), France (1998 as player, 2018 as coach)

Out of them only **Beckenbauer** and **Deschamps** were the captains of the winning squad.

Source: Wikipedia ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_records#Coaching), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_winners#By_coach))